# Why i am not able to change the dummy variable here in my code?

Tags: c

OK, this is a simple bit of procedural code i am trying to write for achieving the functionality of `atoi` function. The thing bothering me is that i am unable to change the `dummy` variable in the `if` block while i can change the `n` variable.The `n` and `dummy` are defined in the same scope.

```
int main()
{

    char *s;

    puts("Enter a string");
    fgets(s,100,stdin);
    int n = 0 , dummy = 1; // both are defined in the same scope 

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
    {
        if(isdigit( s[i] ))    { n = n*10 + (s[i] - '0'); }

        if(1)
        {
            dummy = dummy + 99; // This is the thing not working , program stops executing
            // n = n + 99;  while this works fine
            printf("%d\n", dummy );
        }
    }
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

I can print the `dummy` variable fine but i am not able to assign it a value and when i tried to do that program stops working.If i comment the line involving `dummy` and uncomment the below line using `n`, the program runs fine.

Don't mess with the logic.So what's happening ?

Comment: s is uninitialized; you are getting undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char *s;
```

`s` needs memory to be allocated either *statically* or *dynamically*

```
char s[100];
```

or

```
char *s = NULL;
s = malloc(100);
if (s)
    /* do operations with s */
.
.
if (s)
    free(s);
```

Comment: +1 One small point - you don't need to test `if (s)` before calling `free`.  `free(NULL)` is guaranteed to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem in assigning `dummy` variable but have issues in allocation of variable `s`

```
s = malloc (256);

...
...

if(s)
free(s)
```